# The real roots of $(x-41)^{49}+(x-49)^{41}+(x-2009)^{2009}$

Tags: polynomials, roots

[image]

What all concepts should I know to answer this question? Just give the basic guidelines and then, I will try to solve.

Comment: Hint: Compute and use the derivative of this polynomial.

Comment: Actually computing the derivative is probably overkill. Just noticing that it's a sum of three strictly increasing functions will do.

Comment: Downvoted for title.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Math.SE. Please, try to make the title of your question more informative. E.g., *Why does $a\le b$ imply $a+c\le b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.*

Comment: x cannot be less than 49 since then the f(x) will be negative.......I found the derivative and it doesn't change sign...what does this imply?

Comment: This means that it can only cut x axis atmost once. As the graph doesn't take a turn. You can use Rolle theorem as well.

Comment: http://mathhelpforum.com/algebra/191016-deciding-if-roots-polynomial-real-imaginary.html

Comment: @HenningMakholm That, plus the limits at infinity to ensure at least one root.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: This polynomial is the sum of strictly increasing functions so it is strictly increasing. Hence it have at most ... real root(s).

I think the rest is clear.

Comment: Since the function is strictly increasing it cuts the x-axis only ones which implies that it has only one real root.I think my conclusion is right.

Comment: yes you are right